# Laravel: How to render a view using withError()?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-blade, session-variables

I'm new to Laravel and Blade so please go easy...

I'm using a module found at https://github.com/netojose/laravel-bootstrap-4-forms to generate `bootstrap4` forms and then a `jQuery` function to post the forms via a `ajax` request.

The input is then validated and the forms view rendered and returned as part of a `json` array. The form in the DOM is then replaced with the new `html` (I thought this would be better than handling the errors in `jQuery`).

This is working until there are errors in the user input. The following code renders the form but the `withErrors()` doesn't seem to work unless there is a redirect.

`$formHtml = view('details-form')->with(['formData'=>$requestData])->withErrors($validator, 'detailsErrorBag')->render();`

laravel-bootstrap-4-forms require the errors to be in an errorBag and cannot be passed to the view another way.

As a workaround, the ajax request can be redirected to another route that renders and returns the form html (including the errors) but a 302 redirect after a ajax request doesn't seem the right thing to do.

Is there a way to populate the errorBag in a view for the same request / without a redirect?

Comment: Maybe `->with(['formData' => $requestData,  'errors' => $validator->errors()])` and drop the `->withErrors($validator, 'detailsErrorBag')`? `withErrors()` is generally called with 1 argument, `$validator`, and modifies the global `$errors` variable, but I personally haven't seen the 2nd argument, so I'm not sure of usage there.

Comment: I've tried that. The bootstrap4 forms module seems to only look in the session for errors.

Comment: Ah, I see. You can manually set session values at runtime via `session()->put($key, $value)`, so something like `session()->put('detailsErrorBag', $validator->errors())`, but you might run into issues with persistence of that session (`put()` adds it until explicitly removed/destroyed, could use `session()->flash()` instead, but not sure if that'll work)